# Short way to std::bind member function to object instance, without binding parameters

Tags: c++, stdbind

I have a member function with several arguments. I'd like to bind it to a specific object instance and pass this to another function. I can do it with placeholders:

```
// actualInstance is a MyClass*
auto callback = bind(&MyClass::myFunction, actualInstance, _1, _2, _3);
```

But this is a bit clumsy - for one, when the number of parameters changes, I have to change all the bind calls as well. But in addition, it's quite tedious to type all the placeholders, when all I really want is to conveniently create a "function pointer" including an object reference.

So what I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
auto callback = objectBind(&MyClass::myFunction, actualInstance);
```

Does anyone know some nice way to do this?

Comment: There has been a suggestion to allow something like `bind(&MyClass::myFunction, actualInstance, std::placeholders::all)` to do this

Comment: Ok - do you know why it wasn't included in the standard?

Comment: Because it was only proposed last month, so noone's implemented it, let alone proposed it for the standard yet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> objectBind(R (C::* func)(Args...), C& instance) {
    return [=](Args... args){ return (instance.*func)(args...); };
}
```

then:

```
auto callback = objectBind(&MyClass::myFunction, actualInstance);
```

note: you'll need overloads to handle CV-qualified member functions. ie:

```
template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> objectBind(R (C::* func)(Args...) const, C const& instance) {
    return [=](Args... args){ return (instance.*func)(args...); };
}
```

Comment: This assumes `myFunction` isn't cv-qualified, so would need to be tweaked if it is

Comment: Any particular reason you took the address and did `(&instance)->*func` instead of `instance.*func`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely is there a better way of doing so besides adding a bunch of overloads?

Comment: @David That was leftover from an edit. I'll change it to `.*`

Comment: Sadly, I don't think so, no. You got my upvote, I'm just pointing the cv-quals issue out for the benefit of anyone who uses the code

Comment: What if `C::*func` returns `void`?

Comment: @David it doesn't change anything. The `std::function` handles that.

Comment: @Pubby thanks for the code! I was hoping there is some way to do it using only the std library, but this will certainly do.